# Magento installation through PuTTY SSH

Tags: magento, ssh

So I've been following [this](https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/how-to-install-magento-2-3-and-build-a-web-server/263#chapter3) guide to setup magento and get a webpage running. However, when I try to run this command;

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.0 .
```

I get this error in my PuTTY;

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/composer ~1.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/composer[1.4.0] from composer repo (https://repo.packagist.org) but magento/composer[1.0.2, ..., 1.6.0] from composer repo (https://repo.magento.com) has higher repository priority. The packages with higher priority do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable. See https://getcomposer.org/repoprio for details and assistance.
```

I'm a beginner to Magento so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ibrahim

Answer (score 0):

That error looks like what happens when you try installing any Magento 2 release prior to 2.4.2 using Composer 2.x, which I'm pretty sure is what you are using if you were following that guide you linked to. Magento didn't add support for Composer 2 until the [2.4.2 release](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html). So you would need to either downgrade your composer version to the latest Composer 1.x or install Magento 2.4.2 instead.